# modal analysis of a wind turbine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

I have to do a vibration mechanics project for university and I was thinking of doing the modal analysis of a wind turbine, only I don't know how to evaluate the results I get. With what I should compare the frequencies relating to the modes of vibration?

Comment: Lots of work been done on this, especially for maintenance prediction.

Answer (score 0):

The major forcing frequencies on a windturbine are likely to be blade passing frequency (BPF), and its odd harmonics, ie 1 3 5 7...